# Exported Jar file behaving differently compared to within Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, export, lotus-notes

I am developing a java application which isnt too complex. It connects to a Lotus Notes database to extract an embedded attatchment from a notes database and downloads it to a specified directory, in my case ("C:\Batch Printer\" + attatchmentname). The application works perfectly when ran within eclipse and does the job i require it to, however, i am now at a point where i need to extract the file to a runnable JAR. When i do this and run it the program no longer downloads the file. Another aspect of the program involves printing a file, which seems to work fine. It is just the issue of downloading the file. Do i need to run the jar file with administrator privledges or something? has anyone else had an issue similar?

I figure you dont need to see any code as it is working correctly except on export.

Any help much appreciated.
Ross.

Comment: To elaborate on this, i compiled through the command line, and got this error:

Exception in thread "Thread 4" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\nlsxbe.dll: Can't load a 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.

Comment: You're apparently running your code under a 32 bit JVM when running under Eclipse, but under a 64 bit JVM when running it outside of eclipse. The Lotus Notes classes require loading a 32 bit DLL called nlsxbe.dll, and the 32 bit JVM can do that, but the 64 bit JVM cannot.

Comment: Just guessing: The complete notes- client is 32Bit and cannot be used from a 64Bit environment. Compile your jar as 32Bit (if this is possible) should do the trick.

Comment: The only way i was able to solve this issue was copying my whole project over to a machine which was running Windows 7, eclipse and JVM all in 32bit. The application performed as it was suppose to when compiled and ran as a runnable JAR on this machine. I still however have the problem of not being able to run the JAR file on a 64bit system. I have tried changing my target platform to x86 and x86_64 but neither work. Still that same notes error regarding the DLL. Will this never work on a 64 bit system?